How is called L1 norm of L2 norm of components of the vector?
In TV regularization relatively important role has a norm, which in the discrete case of e.g. one object $v \in R^n \times R^n$ has the form
$$\|w\|_1, \mbox{where } w^i = \| v^i \|_2= \sqrt{(v^i_1)^2+(v_2^i)^2} \mbox{ and } \|.\|_1 \mbox{ is classical } L1 \mbox{ norm in } \mathbb{R}^n.$$
So it is L1 norm of L2 norms of components and I wish to have proper name for it. In the context of TV minimization, where $v$ is gradient, the norm is called isotropic TV norm. But how to call this kind of norm in general where I don't have to deal with derivatives?

To me, this looks like an $L_{2,1}$ matrix norm, although I'm not really sure I got your norm definition right.
